# How to align CircleAvatar to bottom Row widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I want to set a ListView of Cards which each have minimum 3 CirclerAvatar images, as this:

[image: wanted]

***the green one should be the same as the one next to it

this is my code so far, could not figure out how to align them all to the bottom of the card. I tried Align widget but seems it is not the solution.

```
ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    maxRadius: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 100),
                    minRadius: 25.0,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_user.profilePictureURL),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    maxRadius: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 165),
                    minRadius: 25.0,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_user.profilePictureURL),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

This is the Result :

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Row, add this:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
```